# Frequency table for intervals

Tags: r

I saved data into the object `datos` so I could calculate AF (absolute frequency) and RF(relative frequency) for a continuous variable in column V1. But I want to have the frequencies be in intervals.

I don't really know how to do it so I need your help. If anyone has any idea about how to do it, here is my code:

- `k` is the number of intervals I'm using
- and `largo` is the quantity of data I have.

```
read.table("datos.txt", header = FALSE)-> datos
largo<-length(datos$V1)
k<- (1+log2(largo))   
k<-round(k,digits = 0)  
vectordatos <- datos$v1  
histograma<-hist(datos$V1,breaks=k)  
FA<-table(datos$V1)  
FR<-table(datos$V1)/largo  
FA  
FR
```

The `datos` object is as follows:

```
datos = structure(list(V1 = c(6.16, 5.83, 5.66, 3.63, 1.38, 9.64, 7.46, 
    5.34, 7.93, 8.5, 4.18, 5.18, 10.27, 5.41, 4.76, 4.67, 10.02, 
    7.1, 5.38, 8.55, 4.85, 8.28, 2.9, 7.18, 6.54, 5.66, 7.26, 6.45, 
    3.97, 6.55, 5.15, 7.83, 5.52, 7.21, 7.3, 6.19)), class = "data.frame", row .names = c(NA, 
    -36L))
```

Comment: The question is not clear, intervals of what? Do you want to bin the data? If yes, see what's the return value of [`hist`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html), namely, `histograma$breaks`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to create k intervals and `table` to represent the frequency per interval. You can use the following code:

```
table(cut(datos$V1,k))
```

Output:

```
(1.37,2.86] (2.86,4.34] (4.34,5.83] (5.83,7.31] (7.31,8.79] (8.79,10.3] 
          1           4          11          11           6           3
```